Lodash failed to format string if it contains roman numbers
I'm trying to format string using Lodash camelCase function, but it's modifying content itself
_.camelCase("Gladiator II");
'gladiatorIi'

How can I do this properly?

it recognises 2 'I's so it is doing what it is supposed to

maybe match a regex and replace the roman numerals with a placeholder and then turn the string to camelcase and then replace back the placeholder with the roman numeral

What did you expect? What should happen with "LIV"? How can you be sure that is intended as a Roman numeral and not a name?

"I'm trying to format string using lodash camelCase function but it's modifying content itself" What's the difference between modifying a string and modifying string content?

Lodash is doing exactly what it's supposed to. It's a very very lightweight set of javascript utilities.
First go read its source, it'll only take 10-20 seconds. Then take a minute to understand what you're asking it to do: Handle all different natural language scenarios that are exceptions to "make the first letter of a string lower case, capitalize subsequent first letters of each word"
For example: conorMcGregor (the Irish fighter) would be your expected output for _.camelCase("conormcgregor")
Expecting to handle roman numerals is no different. My question is: why do you need to camel case roman numerals? Is your use case specific to roman numerals? If so, you can handle that, but probably not with lodash.
If your use case is ONLY to not un-capitalize the numerals then you could conditionally detect the numeral part of the string, separate it from the rest and call lodash only on the remainder.
If your use case is more general than <part_to_be_camel_cased> <numeral> i.e Gladiator II then you've got a bigger problem on your hands.
